# await and event handler

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, eventhandler

It's permitted to convert and usual event handler from void to Task based and await it like below?

```
Something.PropertyChanged += async (o, args) => await IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged(o, args);  
Something.PropertyChanged -= async (o, args) => await IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged(o, args);  

private Task IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (IsSomthingEnabled)
   {
       return SomeService.ExecuteAsync(...);
   }

   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Or do it like this?

```
Something.PropertyChanged += IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged;  
Something.PropertyChanged -= IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged;  

private void IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (IsSomthingEnabled)
   {
       _ = SomeService.ExecuteAsync(...);
   }
}
```

**Update:**
Or this one, I know that the use Task void It should be banned, because exception it's not catched, but maybe for the case of an Eventhandler it's ok since the Eventhandler doesn't return.

```
Something.PropertyChanged += IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged;  
Something.PropertyChanged -= IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged;  

private async void IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (IsSomthingEnabled)
   {
       await = SomeService.ExecuteAsync(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: event handlers don't return so there is nothing to wait for, if you need a response from a event then you should create an event arg that has a await-able value, (most likely an even in its own right)

Comment: it make sense for me, thanks.

Comment: The correct syntax is the second with `async void`. This is the only case where `async void ` should be used

Comment: You ***might*** be looking for a `TaskCompletionSource` to fire a method; and wait for an event; to `await` it

Comment: Are you asking how to write an asynchronous event handler or how to await an event?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm asking how to properly propagate and await my async method which is called inside an event handler, should I use discard operator or return a task and await it like in the first exp.

Comment: you don't need the = between await and the item being awaited

Comment: @MselmiAli you can await a single event with a `TaskCompletionSource`. If, as I suspect, you want to await *multiple* events you'll need `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. I posted an answer that shows how to do both

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax for asynchronous event handlers is :

```
Something.PropertyChanged += IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged;  
... 

private async void IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged(object sender,
                                                   PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (IsSomethingEnabled)
   {
       await SomeService.ExecuteAsync(...);
   }
}
```

This allows awaiting asynchronous operations inside the event handler without blocking the UI thread. This can't be used to await for an event in some other method though.

**Awaiting a single event**

If you want some other code to await for an event to complete you need a TaskCompletionSource. This is explained in [Tasks and the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap).

```
public Task<string> OnPropChangeAsync(Something x)
{
     var options=TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously;
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(options);
     x.OnPropertyChanged += onChanged;
     return tcs.Task;

     void onChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         tcs.TrySetResult(e.PropertyName);
         x.OnPropertyChanged -= onChanged;
     }
     
}

....

async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    var sth=new Something();
    ....
    var propName=await OnPropertyChangeAsync(sth);
   
    if (propName=="Enabled" && IsSomethingEnabled)
    {
        await SomeService.ExecuteAsync(...);
    }

}
```

This differs from the example in two places:

1. The event handler delegate gets unregistered after the event fires. Otherwise the delegate would remain in memory as long as `Something` did.
2. `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` ensures that any continuations will run on a separate thread. The default is to run them on the same thread that sets the result

This method will await only a single event. Calling it in a loop will create a new TCS each time, which is wasteful.

**Awaiting a stream of events**

It wasn't possible to easily `await` multiple events until [IAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=net-5.0) was introduced in C# 8. With `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` and [Channel](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels), it's possible to create a method that will send a stream of notifications :

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<string> OnPropChangeAsync(Something x,CancellationToken token)
{
     var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
     //Finish on cancellation
     token.Register(()=>channel.Writer.TryComplete());
     x.OnPropertyChanged += onChanged;
     
     return channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync();

     async void onChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         channel.Writer.SendAsync(e.PropertyName);
     }
     
}

....

async Task MyAsyncMethod(CancellationToken token)
{  
    var sth=new Something();
    ....
    await foreach(var prop in OnPropertyChangeAsync(sth),token)
    {
   
        if (propName=="Enabled" && IsSomethingEnabled)
        {
           await SomeService.ExecuteAsync(...);
        }
    }

}
```

In this case, only one event handler is needed. Every time an event occurs the property named is pushed to the `Channel`. `Channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync()` is used to return an `IAsyncEnumerable<string>` that can be used to loop asynchronously. The loop will keep running until the `CancellationToken` is signaled, in which case the writer will go into the `Completed` state and the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` will terminate.

Comment: Plus 1, always great answers and covered all bases

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from Microsoft's article [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming), and specifically from the [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) section:

> Void-returning async methods have a specific purpose: to make asynchronous event handlers possible. [...] Event handlers naturally return void, so async methods return void so that you can have an asynchronous event handler.

Based on this, your third approach is the correct one:

```
private async void IsButtonVisible_PropertyChanged(object sender,
    PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (IsSomethingEnabled)
   {
       await SomeService.ExecuteAsync();
   }
}
```

Your first approach (`+= async (o, args) => await`) is technically equivalent, but it's not recommended because it is idiomatic and may cause confusion to future maintainers.

Your second approach (`_ = SomeService.ExecuteAsync(`) launches the asynchronous operation in a fire-and-forget fashion, which is rarely a good idea because your application completely loses track of this task. It also [elides async and await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), which opens another can of worms.

Answer (score 1):

the syntax for an async Event Handler is

```
async void handler(object sender,EventArgs args){}
```

and as Events don't return there is nothing to await for, so waiting for them is pointless

however if you need a response from an event then you can use the EventsArgs class to provide the response, eg

```
class FeedbackEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    event EventHandler Completed;
    Complete(){
        this.Completed(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

then you can use it as

```
event EventHandler<FeedbackEventArgs> myFeedbackEvent;

args = new FeedbackEventArgs();
args.Completed += OnCompleted;
this.myFeedbackEvent(this,args)
```

note if your handler is not async then you can assume that you code was paused while the event occurred, in which case you can just read a property from the eventArg rather than having to trigger an event

```
class FeedbackEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    int result{get;set;}
}

event EventHandler<FeedbackEventArgs> myFeedbackEvent;

this.myFeedbackEvent(this,args)
args.result //this will be the result set in the sync handler
```

as noted by @Panagiotis this is a conceptual example not a working example

Comment: The first part is correct, the second isn't. While that code can run (with several fixes), everything runs on the main thread. To actually await an event you need a TaskCompletionSource

Comment: you don't need as TaskCompletionSource , however that is a simple way to avoid cross threading issues